# PHP MySQL How To and Performance

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm struggling a bit on the best way to do this with as little performance hit as possible.

Here's the setup...

Search results page with search refining filters that make an AJAX call to a PHP handler which returns a new (refined) set of results.

I have 4 tables that contain all of the data I need to connect to in the PHP handler code.

Table 1 - Main table of records with main details

Table 2 - Ratings for each product from professional rating company #1

Table 3 - Ratings for each product from professional rating company #2

Table 4 - Ratings for each product from professional rating company #3

The refiners on the search results page are jquery sliders with ranges from the lowest allowed rating to the highest for each.

When a slider handle is moved, a new AJAX call is made with the new value(s) and the database query will run to create a fresh set of refined results.

Getting the data I need from Table 1 is the easy part. What I'm struggling with is how to efficiently include a join on the other 3 tables and only picking up rows that match the refining values/ranges.  Table 2, 3, and 4 all have multiple columns for year (2004-2012) and when I made an initial attempt to put it all into one query, it bogged down.

Table 2, 3, and 4 hold the various ratings for each record in Table 1.

The columns in Table 2, 3, and 4 are...
id - productID - y2004 - y2005 - y2006 - y2007 - ... you get the idea.

Each year column has a numeric value for each record (default is 0).

What I need to do is efficiently select records that match the refiner ranges selected by the user across all 4 tables at once.

An example refiner search would be...get all records from Table 1 where price is between $25 and $50 AND where Table 2 records have a rating (from any year/column) between 1 - 4 AND where Table 3 records have a rating (from any year/column) between 80 - 100 AND where Table 4 records have a rating (from any year/column) between 80 - 100.

Any advice on how to set this up with as much performance as possible?

Comment: How many results are we talking about on the initial search on average? It might be easier to load them ALL and do the filtering with just JS - skip the winding down with MySQL, do it all in Javascript. Of course this would depend on the amount of records to begin with as you dont want to bog down the browser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a different table structure. You should merge Table 2, 3 and 4 into a single `ratings` table with the following structure:

```
id | productID | companyID | year | rating
```

Then you could rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
JOIN ratings r ON p.id = r.productID
WHERE p.price BETWEEN 25 AND 50
    AND (
        ( r.companyID = 1 AND r.rating BETWEEN 1 AND 4 )
        OR ( r.companyID = 2 AND r.rating BETWEEN 80 AND 100 )
        OR ( r.companyID = 3 AND r.rating BETWEEN 80 AND 100 )
    )
```

This way the performance would surely increase. Also, your tables will be more scalable, both with the years and the number of companies.

One more thing: if you have a lot of fields in your `products` table, it might be more useful to execute 2 queries instead of joining. The reason for this is that you are fetching redundant data - every joined row will have the columns for `product`, even though you only need it once. This is a side-effect of joins, and there is probably a performance threshold where it will be more useful to query twice than to join. It is up to you to decide if/when that is the case.

Comment: Thanks Grampa - I changed my table structure to what you suggested, loaded up the new query, and everything is lightning fast. Thank you!